# Constraints in inherited list of abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, constraints, abstraction

I'm hitting a wall in a complex project with a few abstractions implied.
For privacy purposes, I have tried to translate the items in my problem to more common ones, so it may sound a bit ridiculous, but I assure you it makes sense in its original context.

Here goes.

Let's say I have freight transportation (eg. planes and cargo ships)

```
public abstract class Freight { }
public class Ship: Freight { }
public class Plane: Freight { }
```

Now by design choice, freight transportation is meant to transport vehicles. So all freight will have a list or array of vehicles. (let's choose list, in our case)

```
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public abstract class Freight
{
    public List<Vehicle> vehicles { get; }
}
```

Then, also by design choice, it is decided that Planes are only meant to transport Motorbikes, and Ships are only meant to transport Cars. And this is where my question arises. How do I do that ?

My first though was to abstract the list property in the freight, so that it needs to be overriden in specific freight (maybe detailing how it gets loaded differently into the freight), but in doing, I haven't found a way to specify or constraint the content of the abstract list from freight, that ensures all freight must have its list of vehicles.

```
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Motorbike : Vehicle { }
public class Car : Vehicle { }

public abstract class Freight
{
    // This becomes abstract, maybe ?
    public abstract List<Vehicle> vehicles { get; }
}

public class Cargo: Freight
{
    // Tentative #1
    public override List<Vehicle> vehicles where Vehicle : Car { get; }
}

public class Plane: Freight
{
    // Tentative #2
    public override List<Motorbike> vehicles { get; }   
}
```

But none of these seem to work.

My question is : Are there abstraction design concepts that would allow me to reach specifications / constraints goals that I should know and would help me that I am missing ?. Or are there any official (Microsoft) recommendations on this kind of topic on alternative designs to achieve expected behavior ?

To try and clarify the concept is the following (edited after answer) :
The piece of software tries to mimic rules and behaviour of non software. These are described in its own documentation, and the ruleset makes sense for a physical product, its application, and how/what restrictions applies to it during its manufacturing process. I translated this concept to freight transportation because it's the only "simple" example I had in mind, without going in the details of what product my company is manufacturing, and why are these restriction the way they are.

I hope I have been clear enough, I find this as difficult to explain as it is to find a solution for. So I thank you for your trying to understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds very similar to the intro to Eric Lippert's series on [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/), the pay off of which was, to paraphrase, "if you're trying to build a *rules system*, don't expect that the C# type system necessarily will align with those rules"

Comment: This really depends on how you intend to use `Freight`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you. This is an amazing piece of litterature I didn't know about. And as I am trying to "match" a rules system, more than trying to build it, I think I can find something in there where the implementation downsides are fit for the context. I need to study this a little more thoroughly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for generics. Instead of making a list of `Vehicle`, you can give `Freight` a list of `T`, and then constrain `T` to be a subclass of `Vehicle`:

```
public abstract class Vehicle { }
public class Motorbike : Vehicle { }
public class Car : Vehicle { }

public abstract class Freight<T>
   where T: Vehicle
{
    public List<T> Vehicles { get; }
}

public class Ship: Freight<Car>
{
}

public class Plane: Freight<Motorbike>
{
}
```

Comment: What if OP needs to use `Freight` in a non-generic way?

Comment: Then OP should specify the use case in the question more explicitly. I think as written, this is a common design that fits all the requirements mentioned.

Comment: @CompuChip As written, there lacks enough information to advise. Making a class generic is restrictive, and it's not clear why an abstract class is even needed.

Comment: Running a few tests, this seems to suit my needs. And the blog post from @Damien_The_Unbeliever wonderfully complements your answer. Meaning that if the requirements change (about what freights are supposed to do and work), I can find a more appropriate solution there.

I will update the question to clarify that this piece of code is supposed to mimic behavior and rules of non software elements, as is described in its external documentation. This is what makes the whole thing a little tricky.

Comment: @CrumbleZ thanks. If you have time, definitely read through some more of Eric's blog. It's very interesting altogether!

Comment: This is pretty much a replica of Eric Lippert's [Attempt 5](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/30/wizards-and-warriors-part-two/), which he advises against.

Comment: What I was missing from a language perspective, is where I needed the generics (I was looking to place it on the list directly). And your choice fits, because I know my classes will never expand (by product design)

So it's kind of complicated to explain why I need to achieve this, because all design decision of what I'm trying to mimick are intially non-software. Some choices are historical remnants, and some find their origin in physical limitations, which make the whole thing way more complex than it needs for a piece of software.

Thank you very much for your answer! =)